# .NET XML Deserialization for fields with different values

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML:

```
<results>
<row>
    <id>4990321</id>
    <field name="First name">John</field>
    <field name="Last name">Snow</field>
    <field name="Country">USA</field>
    <field name="City">San-Diego</field>
    <field name="Postcode">123456</field>
    <field name="Email">username@stackoverflow.com</field>
    <field name="Message">Hello</field>
</row>
<row>
    ...
<row>
</results>
```

I need to deserialize it in array of objects:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Firstname { set; get; }
    public string Lastname { set; get; }
    public string Country { set; get; }
    public string City { set; get; }
    public string Postcode { set; get; }
    public string Email { set; get; }
    public string Message { set; get; }
}
```

I've tried to implement it using `XmlElementAttribute` and `XmlAttributeAttribute`, but property named `ElementName` doesn't understand XPath, so I couldn't get value of specific field (as `field[name='Email']`)

Who has any ideas how can I do it? Desirable without XDocument parse.

Comment: Have you tried something like this?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx

Comment: @montewhizdoh To use Linq I need to parse it. I wrote in the end of my post that I want to avoid XElement/XDocument. It is very heavy for my task.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to pre-process your data into a form that is more friendly to serialize via an XSLT transform. This can be accomplished in C# via the [XslCompiledTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

A sample XSL file to use would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="results">
        <Employees>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <Employee>
                 <Id><xsl:value-of select="id" /></Id>
                 <Firstname><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='First name']" /></Firstname>
                 <Lastname><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='Last name']" /></Lastname>
                 <Country><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='Country']" /></Country>
            </Employee>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </Employees>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Incomplete but enough for illustration purposes)

In your C# program the transformation is simple:

```
var xslReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(GetXslString()));
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(GetXmlString()));

var transformedStream = new MemoryStream();

var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(transformedStream);
var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

xslt.Load(xslReader);
xslt.Transform(xmlReader, xmlWriter);

transformedStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// Use your transformedStream to deserialize the object
```

.NET fiddle demonstrating this code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8VmjEP)

When this is run against your sample data, it produces outputs similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <Id>4990321</Id>
        <Firstname>Jhon</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Snow</Lastname>
        <Country>USA</Country>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Id>4990322</Id>
        <Firstname>Mike</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Ross</Lastname>
        <Country>UK</Country>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

This should be fairly easy now for the any of the default deserialization tools to take over without advanced document selectors, etc.

Comment: This is a good idea. I had to do something similar once, but instead I used Regex.replace to accomplish it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778780/c-sharp-regex-help-replacing-patterns

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize it by explicitly declaring the order the elements are deserialized in using `Order`:

```
[XmlRoot("results")]
public class Results
{
    [XmlElement("row")]
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", Order = 1)]
    public string Id { set; get; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field", Order = 2)]
    public string Firstname { set; get; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field", Order = 3)]
    public string Lastname { set; get; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field", Order = 4)]
    public string Country { set; get; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field", Order = 5)]
    public string City { set; get; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field", Order = 6)]
    public string Postcode { set; get; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field", Order = 7)]
    public string Email { set; get; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field", Order = 8)]
    public string Message { set; get; }
}
```

You can then deserialize this as such (where `xml` is your XML string):

```
var results = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Results)).Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

Comment: Hm.. That is a good solution. But it will be better if it can be done without binding to order =)

Comment: So inspect the attribute name and bind using that? I think this is impossible - feel free to prove me wrong though! Perhaps creating your own constructor is more appropriate then if this is not appropriate?

Comment: if I want to skip some points and get only 1, 2, and for example 7 elements to my class, eour solution works incorrect. In first and second properties as expected I got right values, but in third one I got value from 3-rd xml element (but expected that I got 7). So there is a bad solution for me.